# Catching remove event on View in Backbone js

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-events

Is there any way to listen to remove/destroy event on the Backbone View.?

I want to do some thing like as below:

```
$(myBackboneView).on('remove', function () {
    // do some processing
});
```

or

```
$(myBackboneView).on('destroy', function () {
    // do some processing
});
```

Thank you in advance. :)

Comment: Yes, I need to do some processing before the view is completely removed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try to override the `View.remove` method::

```
Backbone.View.extend({
    remove: function(){
        // Your processing code here

        Backbone.View.prototype.remove.apply(this, arguments);
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried the following and it works for me:

```
$(myBackboneView.el).on('remove', function () {
    // do some processing
});
```

Is this is a good approach ? Or there is something else better than this?

Comment: The remove event is not part of jQuery, it's added by jQuery UI v1.10.2 and above.

Comment: Small remark: $(myBackboneView.el) is provided by default as myBackboneView.$el, or this.$el, if you're inside the View model.

Comment: Hence myBackboneView.$el should give the same result.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to listen for other views being removed, you can have your base View class trigger a 'remove' event when remove() is called.

```
BaseView = Backbone.View.extend({
    remove: function () {
        this.trigger('remove', this)
        return Backbone.View.prototype.remove.apply(this, arguments)
    }
})
```

Then listen for that whenever you like:

```
this.listenTo(otherView, 'remove', func)
```